# Unix join command with dummy entries

Tags: shell, unix, join, merge

I have a poor understanding of the semantics behind the `join` command. I would like to merge through a shell scrip and add dummy values.

I have two files that I want to merge together. File A has 4 columns with a KEY column. File B has 60K+ columns, with the very first column being the KEY column.

Both keys overlap at ~80%.

Goal: create File C, which is every entry from File A and the matching rows from File B. If A did not match in B, I'd like dummy value "0" to be inserted into every missing field (60K+ fields)

Approach:

As a newbie to shell scripting, I figured a simple `join` would be effective. I sorted File A and B by the KEY value first using `sort -k#` appropriately.

```
join -a1 -1 2 -2 1 -e "0" file.A file.B > file.C
```

Now, how does **join** see the fields/columns its looking at? File B has 60k-1 columns that are spaced as:

```
KEY 1 0     1 1     2 4     0 1 ...
```

Now, when I tried my command, file C has the correct number of entries, but I couldn't figure out how to add the missing values. File A has entries that file B does not have, and I'd like to place the null value 0 in every column that was not matched in file A by file B.

Thus, in file C, the result should be (according to my understanding of **join**):

```
KEY A1 A2 A3 A4 1 0     1 1     2 4     0 1 ... 
KEY A1 A2 A3 A4 0 0     0 0     0 0     0 0 ...
```

The spacing AFTER the joining doesn't matter to me, but the file B is created with the alternating tab-space-tab-space format.

Why isn't `join -e "0"` adding in my dummy values when I asked it to? I would also appreciate any other shell strategies to do this. I know I can merge in perl by running it through line by line (or R if it didn't take so long to load), but I feel shell is more powerfully equipped for this.

**EDIT**

The data in teh file is mixed. The first 5 columns are identifying strings in file A, and in file B there is a key string and single alphanumeric characters in each of the additional. File A will always be small (no more than 1 MB), but file B can stretch up to 2+ GB.

Attempted R:
`df <- read.table("file.B", header=FALSE, fill=TRUE)`

Comment: How big are the files, what is the nature of their contents (all numeric, mixed types, etc), and how did you try to read them into R?

Comment: It seems that the parameter -e does not work without explicit definition of output format (parameter -o). You can try to define the output format but 60k+ columns is too many for do it.

Comment: You might want to heed the notes in `?read.table` regarding memory usage: "These functions can use a surprising amount of memory when reading large files.  There is extensive discussion in the [R Data Import/Export manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html), supplementing the notes here."

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the help. I guess the shell approach won't work here, and R won't either. I was hoping to avoid perl, but that looks like the only choice.

Comment: Don't want nag you, but IMHO if you have 60K fields in one line - it is an BAD data model. As you see yourself, it too hard to manage, edit, simply - work with it... IMHO, would be much better to have 6000 files and each with 10 columns (+1 key column). But, maybe only seeing it wrong and your mileage is vary... ;)

Comment: I agree! The data is horrible. Each row is a person and the columns are an equivalence of their DNA (which is why its so long). An analysis tool (Merlin) can only accept rows of data for analysis. I'm chunking it into 20 blocks to give to different processors, but only AFTER its been put together (unfortunately). Thanks for the thought - as a beginner, I'll keep that in mind when I plan things in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I read in the `join` info page:

```
`-e STRING'
     Replace those output fields that are missing in the input with
     STRING.  I.E. missing fields specified with the `-12jo' options.
```

I inferred that `-o` was required. Try this:

```
join -a1 -1 2 -2 1 -o auto -e "0" file.A file.B > file.C
```